# Where To Place Firebase's OnAuthStateChanged-Method In A VueJS-Application?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I'd like to trigger the `onAuthStateChanged`-method of Firebase in my VueJS-Application.

Currently I am not able to stay logged in as a certain user, the `onAuthStateChanged`-method seems not to run.

my action is kicked off by ...

```
beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.dispatch('update_session')
}
```

... in my main App-Component.

the mutation looks like:

```
update_session(state) {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged().then((user) => {
        if (user) {
            // USE USER KEY
            state.user.current.key = user.uid
            // USE USER ROLE
            users.child(state.user.current.key).on('value', (snapshot) => {
                state.user.current.role = snapshot.val().role
            })
        }
    })
}
```

**EDIT**:

Of course I am using an Action:

```
update_session({ commit }) {
    commit('update_session')
}
```

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` doesn't return a Promise. So I think that line should be `auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {`, not `auth.onAuthStateChanged().then((user) => {`

Comment: the onAuthStateChanged gets called on every auth state change, so for example when you reload your page, it will get called with firebase data from your local storage. you will need to handle this globally, its in my main.js file.

Comment: thanksd, you've done it. THANKS. :D

Comment: @phoet why not make this an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

the `onAuthStateChanged` gets called on every auth state change.

so for example when you reload your page, it will get called with firebase data from your local storage.

you will need to handle this globally, its in my `main.js` file

Comment: but if I keep tracking of the user status by vuex do I still need to use onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: well, you can't keep track of the internal state of firebase. that's what you need this callback for.